# tail/head all line except X last/first Lines

Tags: bash, ssh, centos, tail, head

for example i have this file :

```
cat myfile
1
2
3
4
5
```

i want to print all lines except first 2 line . output should be like this :

```
tail -n $(( $(wc -l myfile | awk '{print $1}') - 2 )) myfile
3
4
5
```

Yes , out put is correct. but there is a problem , we have 5 line in this sample file right ? if i use more that 5 in this command output should be empty but it is not !!!

> tail -n $(( $(wc -l myfile | awk '{print $1}') - ***NUMBER*** ))
>   myfile

this outout should be empty but it is not

```
tail -n $(( $(wc -l myfile | awk '{print $1}') - 8 )) myfile

1
2
3
4
5
```

myfile can contain X lines...
Thanks for help

Answer (score 42):

`tail -n+3` outputs all lines starting from the third one.

`head -n-3` outputs all lines except for the last three.

Comment: line number are variable and i dont know how many line there are . want to keep all except last 3 lines

Comment: That's not what you described in the question, but `head -n-3` should give you what you need.

Comment: i have edit question. but this file is output of a script and we dont know how many line have ...

Comment: You don't need to know the number of lines.

Comment: tried is it not what i need for example if i want have all line except 8 lines but i have 5 line only .so output should be empty :tail -n-8 myfile

1

2

3

4

5

Comment: @behnam: Use `+` with `tail`, not `-`, as I did.

Comment: slightly tangential comment: i just came across a util that is similar to `tail` called Debian `buthead`, which more people should have the chance to enjoy: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/buthead/buthead.1.en.html  (it outputs all "but head"... as in "all but N lines from the head")

Comment: FWIW, this worked great for me just now. I wanted everything BUT the first line of a file, and `tail -n+2 file` did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for posterity.

given the input (as posted by OP),

```
cat << EOF > myfile
1
2
3
4
5
EOF
```

you can solve the problem using awk

```
awk 'FNR > 2 {print $1}' myfile
```

will yield desired result

```
3
4
5
```

tested with awk version (GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2))